# OpenCV contour detection: Extract rectangular video element out of entire Youtube webpage

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Working on extracting the rectangle hosting the Youtube video element out of the entire screenshot of webpage.
I'm struggling to find any solution that works with good accuracy across different videos and page form factors.

Attaching a sample instance I am interested in-
[image]

Here's the most promising solution I've found yet:

1. Thresholding
2. FindContours
3. Look in Largest Bounding Rects

   ```
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = clahe(gray, 5, (3, 3))
    img_blur = cv2.blur(gray, (9, 9))
    img_th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 51, 2)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_th,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
   ```

Contours Look like:
[image]

Large contours(boundingRect) found:
[image]

What I wanted out of the image was the central large blue rectangle hosting video content.
Clearly not showing up in detected contours by default.

Tried Canny as well instead of thresholding but no good.
Any suggestions on what approach I can take to solve this problem? (on how to handle detected contours or maybe generate a more filtered set of contours)

I feel this problem should be simpler than many image processing task involving real world images as objects here have perfect boundaries.

Comment: Threshold on black using cv2.inRange() and invert. Then use morphology to clean it up before getting the largest contour.

Comment: great input. thresholding on black+ invert does give a better image to work with. For case without the red bar appearing on video, it works great. However, for given case with red line over video, it still fails. Any way to filter that out?

Comment: Why do you need to remove the red lines?  Is that not part of the video?  You could threshold on red. Then use HoughLines to find the lines or if they are always horizontal, then morphology should work on the red threshold image to make a mask which could then be used  to remove the red lines.

Comment: I dont need to remove the red line, I want that to be part of result, however its messing up the contours is what I meant.
I want to have a generic enough solution without point fix for red line.

Comment: So then why does not thresholding on black and inverting (plus morphology to clean up) work for you. I do not understand why the red line would cause an issue. Can you explain and perhaps show your result from thresholding on black, etc.

Comment: get the DOM, it contains the coordinates. -- why even do this from a screenshot of the web page? just download the video itself, then use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Able to find a solution to this use case, Thanks to @fmw42.
Sharing the solution here and further insights for solving similar tasks.

1. Binary Thresholding:

> InRange- since we are only interested in getting the rectangle and not its inner details. This reduces the problem better than adaptive thresholding.
> [image]

2. Morphology:

> Open MORPH_OPEN (in this case) to cleanup noise.
> [image]

3. Contour Detection:

> [image]

```
gray = cv2.inRange(gray, 0, 20)
showImageWithResize('InRange', gray)
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
showImageWithResize('BinaryImage', gray)


kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
gray = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=2)

showImageWithResize('Morphology', gray)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

result_image = cv2.drawContours(image.copy(), contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 5)
showImageWithResize('contours', result_image)

contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
showImageWithRects("rect", image.copy(), [cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])])

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

To accurately extract the rectangle hosting the YouTube video element from a screenshot of a webpage, you can try the following approach:

Preprocessing:

Convert the image to grayscale.
Apply histogram equalization or CLAHE to enhance contrast.
Blur the image to reduce noise.
Edge Detection:

Use Canny edge detection to identify edges in the image.
Contour Detection:

Find contours in the edge-detected image.
Filter contours based on size and aspect ratio to remove small and irrelevant contours.
Rectangle Extraction:

Identify the largest rectangular contour that is likely to represent the video element.
Further refine the rectangle by ensuring it is positioned in the center of the image and has dimensions consistent with a video player.

Your code would look something like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image
image = cv2.imread('webpage_screenshot.png')

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply CLAHE for contrast enhancement
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
gray = clahe.apply(gray)

# Blur the image
blurred = cv2.blur(gray, (9, 9))

# Edge detection using Canny
edges = cv2.Canny(blurred, 30, 150)

# Find contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Filter contours based on size and aspect ratio
filtered_contours = [cnt for cnt in contours if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 1000]
filtered_contours = [cnt for cnt in filtered_contours if cv2.arcLength(cnt, True) > 100]

# Sort contours by area in descending order
filtered_contours = sorted(filtered_contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

# Extract the largest rectangle
if filtered_contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(filtered_contours[0])
    
    # Draw the rectangle on the original image
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Display the result
    cv2.imshow('Rectangle', image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
else:
    print("No rectangle found.")
```

Comment: you could use a inplace sort

Comment: Canny doesnt give any better results. I am able to get contours similar to those I get with thresholding after enough CLAHE enhancement. 
Simple filtering of those contours to get the desired rect still doesnt work.